# Nginx: How to reverse proxy 2 specific ports to another specific ports with the same server_name?

Tags: nginx, server, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to use Nginx reverse proxy port 80 to port 5000 and port 8080 to port 8081.
I've configured ssl so GET `http://DOMAIN:80` with redirect to port 443 - this works fine.

I'v configured another server block with subdomain `server_name api.DOMAIN` listen to port 8080. The reverse proxy suppose to pass requests to `localhost:8081` but when I run 
`curl http://api.DOMAIN:8080/` I get `Operation timed out`.
It seems that Nginx does not actually listen to port 8080 although when running

```
lsof -i :8080
```

I get:

```
nginx   20836     root   10u  IPv4 3939217      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
nginx   20840 www-data   10u  IPv4 3939217      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

The configuration I use:

```
server {

        server_name DOMAIN;

        location / {
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

             proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate PATH_TO_PEM_FILE/PEM.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}

 server {

        server_name api.DOMAIN;
        listen 8080;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
        }
}

server {
    if ($host = DOMAIN) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }



        server_name askalgotrader.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What `nginx -t` command says in detail?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out. Turned out that port `8080` was blocked by the firewall.
`ufw allow 8080` solved it.